# PHP telegram bot: send message all users from in id.txt

Tags: php, bots, telegram, sendmessage, allusersprofile

I created a php telegram boat. In this case, I will store the user id in the id.txt file.

```
$message = $update->message;
$text1 = $message->text;
$fadmin = $message->from->id;
$baza = file_get_contents("id.txt");

$saqla2 = "$baza\n$fadmin";
file_put_contents("id.txt", $saqla2);
```

Then how do I send a message to every registered user? So you need to send a message to all the minorities.

```
$text2 = str_replace("/xabar","",$text1);
  $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/sendMessage?chat_id= //there all user id from $baza // &text=$text2");
```

Comment: You must send ‍`message` to users one by one

Comment: Is there no other way?

Comment: No . The telegram does not allow you to send a message to all users simultaneously

Comment: Other bots can do that

Comment: other bots??!!! what ??

Comment: chat_id : integer or string  : Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target channel

Comment: There must be something

Comment: How do I send a message to all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can store `user_ids` in a text file : 
for example `list.txt` :

```
108926499
108926497
108926496
```

now send a message to all users `index.php`:

```
<?php
$apiToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$users=file_get_contents('list.txt');
$users=explode("\n",$users);
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    if (empty($user)) continue;
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $user,
        'text' => 'Hello world!'
    ];

    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
}
```

Comment: In this case, the message is repeated many times. Can you just take a one trip? `if($text1 == "/send_all" && in_array($fadmin, $admin)){
 $baza=explode("\n",$baza); 
 foreach ($baza as $fadmin){
     if (empty($fadmin)) continue;
      $data = [
          'chat_id' => $fadmin,
          'text' => 'hello world!'
      ];

      $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
 }
}`

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly? please explain more

Comment: I do not speak English and use Google Translate. Errors are an excuse. If i use the code you write, the "Hello World" will be returned to the user. I only need to send a message once!

Comment: My code, first reads all the users from the file and then sends them a message in the telegram.

Comment: Do you want to send a message to the user when the user sends a message to ‌BOT?

Comment: For example, get 4 id in list.txt. I used your code. The bot sends a message to the first id number four times, twice to the id number 3 times, to the third id number twice, to the fourth id once. This is a mistake! Only one message should be sent to all id numbers!

Comment: I once again tested the code. For each user, only a message was sent.
Are you sure you copy the codes?

Comment: I saved the code inside `index.php` and run `php index.php ` .

Comment: forgive me. Thank you very much. I'm in error. I've just added an id in list.txt several times.

Comment: you're welcome
So please accept my answer and close the topic.